# sending id vlaue with checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want all checkboxes to appear as “false” initially.  CBColumn.DataPropertyName = "id"; is causing all checkboxes to be checked. But when I remove the line CBColumn.DataPropertyName = "id"; then I can’t send the “id” value.

I want all checkboxes to appear as “false” initially.  CBColumn.DataPropertyName = "id"; is causing all checkboxes to be checked. But when I remove the line CBColumn.DataPropertyName = "id"; then I can’t send the “id” value. I want to sendi d value. How can I succed this?

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CBColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
   CBColumn.Width = 30;
   CBColumn.FalseValue = "0";
   CBColumn.TrueValue = "1";
   CBColumn.DataPropertyName = "id";
   CBColumn.ReadOnly = false;
   dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CBColumn);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5mAD.png)

Comment: can you try this:
CBColumn.FalseValue = false;
CBColumn.TrueValue = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a DataTable to load the DataGridView you can add a new DataColumn after loading the data, before assigning the DataTable to the DataGridView as followings were `dt` is the DataTable. `DefaultValue = false` will render as false in the DataGridView.

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Process", DataType = typeof(bool), DefaultValue = false });
```

Then since the column is added to the end of the columns, set the position, here to the first column.

```
dt.Columns["Process"]!.SetOrdinal(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

When your app loads initially, you can loop through the grid and set all of them to what ever value you want.

```
foreach (DataGridViewCheckBoxRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[CBColumn.Name].Value = false;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the amount of data he is loading into the grid, this can be very slow.

Comment: It gives this error.
Hata CS0246 DataGridViewCheckBoxRow' türü veya ad alanı adı bulunamadı (bir using yönergeniz veya derleme başvurunuz mu eksik?') DataGridViewCheckBoxRow' type or namespace name not found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?